# --net equivalent in docker compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

When i am running my docker container,I am explicitly providing network as `host`.

```
docker run -d \
    --net=host \
    --name=zookeeper \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000 \
    confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0
```

How can i provide the same network in `docker-compose.yaml` file so that all container run within this host?

Comment: `network_mode: "host" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as below in your service definition -

`network_mode: "host"`

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode